# Как обратиться к контексту на втором уровне вложенности объекта?

Tags: javascript

Как обратиться к контексту test из объекта objWithFunc?

```
var test = {
    a: 0,
  objWithFunc: {
    b: 1,
    func1: function () {
        console.log(this.a) // ???
        }
  },
  func: () => {
    console.log(this)
  }

}
test.objWithFunc.func1(); //??
test.func();
```

Comment: `console.log(test.a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет способа обратиться к содержащему объекту используя встроенные средства.

Только прямое обращение к этому объекту

```
objWithFunc: {
    b: 1,
    func1: function () {
        console.log(test.a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак не получится.

Когда Вы вызываете функцию func1 то this в ней формируется тем объектом, который стоит до точки, т.е. this при вызове равен test.objWithFunc

Получить родительский объект из дочернего невозможно.

В приницпе Вы можете сделать bind для функции func1 так, чтобы она указывала на test.

Можно еще сделать так:

```
var main = {
    name : "main object",
    child : {
        name : "child object"
    },
    init : function() {
        this.child.parent = this;
        delete this.init;
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```